# how to get pixels within fixed boundary and changing the color of the pixels

Tags: java, android, opencv, opengl-es

I'm using openCV library to detect facial features like lips and eye.i'have drawn points over lip and eye. now i want to get pixels within the lips and need to change the color of this pixels through the color filter. i know the coordinates where the lips located, using these coordinates how i can get pixels inside lip, how i can change the color and make that changes to reflect on original image. please see the attached screen shot - http://www.flickr.com/photos/108570354@N02/10834522165/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, you need to use one of these functions:

- [fillpoly](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly)
- [fillconvexpoly](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillconvexpoly)

Comment: Hi thanks, can you suggest any alternative methods for this which is written in java

Comment: Hmmmm... In Java, do you receive the image with your points drawn with OpenCV, or do you receive the list of point coordinates (and the original image)? I hope it's the second case, in which I suggest you find an appropriate Java library to draw this polygons.

Comment: it is the second case, openCV will give list of points. using this points i drawn points and lines over image. Could you please advise where i can learn about classical approach on polygon draw?